# strtok not working as expected with spaces in CSV format

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm making a C program which needs to take data on books as input and create an ordered list. The data is to be input in CSV format. The info about each book is the following: "ISBN code", "title", "author", 3 strings.

I am using strtok with a "," delimiter to split the input information into three strings that I then need to pass to an insert function. This seems to be working fine unless there are spaces in the fields. For example, 
`111111,AAA,BBB` will work correctly but
`111111,A AA,BBB` won't.

Here's my code:

```
    Book book; // previously defined struct

    char data[212];

    scanf("%s", data);


    char *field;

    field = strtok(data, ",");
    if(field != NULL) {
        strcpy(book.isbn, field);
    }
    field = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if(field != NULL) {
        strcpy(book.title, field);
    }
    field = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if(field != NULL) {
        strcpy(book.author, field);
    }
```

With this input:
`1,A,B`
I get the output
`1 - A - B`
from a function that should go through the list and print all the fields, separated by a '-', followed by a newline.

With this input:
`1,A A,b`
I get the following output:

```
A - b -
1 - A -
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem: `scanf("%s", data);` will stop at the first whitespace. Solution: `getline(data, sizeof(data), stdin);`

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica `getline` should only be used with dynamically allocated buffers.

Comment: I feel this is probably the solution but I need to make some corrections to make it work. This currently gives me the following error:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LeF3Z5DL

Comment: `getline()` is a POSIX.1-2008 library function so less portable than `fgets()` for example.

Comment: See documentation and example here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html   `char* data = NULL; size_t length = 0; getline( &data, &length,  stdin ) ;`  The buffer is provided dynamically by `getline()` an dthe number of characters written returned in `length`.  It is a hideous and leak-promoting interface - avoid IMO.

Comment: @dbush You're right! (I was actually thinking of `fgets` but posted too quickly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier to `scanf` reads non-whitespace characters.  So if there is a space in the input it will stop reading at the space.

Try using `fgets` instead, which will read a full line of text:

```
fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);
```

Because this function will include a newline in the string it reads it, add `\n` to the delimiter list of your `strtok` calls:

```
field = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are blaming `strtok()`, but that is not the issue - the string is truncated at the space by `scanf()`, so the *input* to `strtok()` is not what you assume it to be.  This is where the use of a debugger would help enormously.

The `scanf()` format specifier can be modified to explicitly specify just '\n' as the string delimiter, but it becomes increasingly arcane and complex to make overrun safe.  Simpler to use `fgets()`.

```
fgets( stdin, data, sizeof(data) ) ;
```